# Как раскрыть панель навигации?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, bootstrap

При уменьшении окна браузера панель навигации сворачивается, но раскрыть её обратно не получается, хотелось бы чтобы при нажатии на кнопку список раскрывался. Как решить данную проблему?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Simple landing page</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merienda:700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toogle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="brand" href="#">Landy</a>
                <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav pull-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Screenshots</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Download</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Панель навигации]
[image: Свернутое панель навигации]

Comment: а где `popper.js` ?

Comment: и можно рабочий ваш вариант на `codepen.io` или другой песочнице?

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич на codepen.io всё работает а в Visual Studio, почему-то нет? Не подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Я попросил скинуть это на codepen ссылкой, не просто так

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич  вот ссылка https://codepen.io/Vasiliy7991/project/editor/AxVmNe

Comment: сейчас заново запустил проект  на codepen.io  список уже не разворачивается.

Comment: вам помог ответ?

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич, не помогло. Список также не раскрывается.

Comment: Он в примере работает а у вас нет? Вы серьезно?

Comment: Да, я думаю проблема в Visual Studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-toggler btn btn-navbar" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse" aria-controls="nav-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </a>
                <a class="brand" href="#">Landy</a>
                <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav pull-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Screenshots</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Download</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в том, что я вместо `data-toggle` написал `data-toogle`

```
<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
```

Предыдущий вариант отправленный Павелом Игоревичем тоже неожиданно заработал.